# Html showing up instead of like button ON IPHONE and IPAD

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like, iweb

I'm using iWeb to design a website and I'm getting html showing up as well as the Like button, when I access my site on iphone and/or ipad.  Anybody have any clues?

Website:  ncdoggydaycare.com

Code is posted here:  ncdoggydaycare.com/Blank.html

Make sure to use a capital "B" in Blank.html

Comment: The Blank.html file is returning a 404 error. Post the HTML code for the Facebook like button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add /Site to that link before the HTML page.

The reason it's showing the HTML is because you're closing the iframe before you've finished with it. Here you go:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fncdoggydaycare&amp;send=false&amp;layout=box_count&amp;width=250&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height="90" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:250px; height:90px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Actually it's not that you hadn't finished with it, you had, but you immediately had HTML code with no opening tag but with a closing iframe tag, probably a copy and paste error. So it was displaying the HTML as text because you didn't tell the browser it was HTML code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Of course it was something so simple and stupid.  I suck at html.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark the answer as correct otherwise it stays as an unanswered question.